# select option html can I have additional tags for searching?

Tags: jquery, html, select, search

I am creating a select option form using [selectize.js](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js) plugin. Example:

```
        <select id="searchme">
            <option>Cat</option>
            <option>Dog</option>
            <option>Mouse</option>
            <option>Horse</option>
        </select>   
        <script>
            $('#searchme').selectize();
        </script>
```

Now, I can easily search for names that I put into the < option > ... < / option > tags. So if I type into the search box Mouse, or Horse, or Cat, or Dog I find the option.

But what if I wanted for example to have "hidden" names for some of the animals. Let's say the cat's name is Jerry, and if I input Jerry into the search box, it would still point to the Cat option.

Is there such a possibility? I can't find anything on the internet that would even point me into this direction.

Comment: you could add data attributes and then [customise](https://select2.org/searching) how results are matched

Comment: your question mentions select2 but your code shows `selectize()`.  which one are you using?

Comment: So sorry! Of course it's selectize(), just corrected that in the post!

Comment: Looks like selectize also allows data attributes to be included: see the `dataAttr` option: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md, you may be able to combine it with the `searchField` option - see this: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/1292

Comment: Thanks Pete! That works!! Thank you :)